# How do I crop an image using a path in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image-processing, rmagick, image-extraction

Here is the path "M276,189h268c5.5,0,10,4.5,10,10v196c0,5.5-4.5,10-10,10H276 c-5.5,0-10-4.5-10-10V199C266,193.5,270.5,189,276,189z"

This is the input image:

[image: Input image]

After applying the path to the image by using the below code

```
draw = Magick::Draw.new
draw.fill 'red'
draw.path path
draw.clip_rule("evenodd")
draw.fill_rule("evenodd")
draw.fill_opacity(0)
draw.draw image
img.trim!
img.write('output.jpg')
```

This is the output image:

[image: Output image]

Now I want to cut the red color part of the image. This means expecting the brown color part only visible.
I used the normal image-level crop method. with this Am able to extract the red color part only
But I want to extract the image other than the red color from the output image.

Here is the sample output for the black image 
[sample output for the black color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3m6dy.png)

Maybe we have to reverse clip or reverse crop to get this ...

Comment: Can you please add an image to the question which shows what the desired output is? Just use any image editor to create a mock so that we know what you're trying to achieve. Its very unclear what "But I want to extract the image other than the red color from the output image" actually entails.

Comment: Are you trying to make a transparent cutout? Cropping means to actually trim the size of an image.

Comment: added sample output https://i.stack.imgur.com/3m6dy.png

Answer (score 0):

The method

img.paint_transparent

will make that red color part as transparent, but we have to pass the color as an argument to the above method. Initially, I tried by giving the color value as red. so it's not worked. Now am reading the one pixel from the image like

redPixel= img.get_pixels(300, 200, 1, 1)[0]

and getting the color from that pixel-like redPixel.to_color and passing the value to the above method ...

we have to set fuzz value to the image

img = Magick::Image.read("diecut.jpg").first

redPixel= img.get_pixels(300, 200, 1, 1)[0]

img.fuzz = '25%'

puts redPixel.to_color

newimage=img.paint_transparent(redPixel.to_color)

newimage.write("outPut.png")

newimage.display